# Anomaly detection on time series with Xgboost algorithm

Tags: time-series, xgboost, forecasting, anomaly-detection

why xgboost algorithm is not useful for anomaly detection on time series?
There are some cases about forecasting on time series. (https://www.kaggle.com/code/robikscube/tutorial-time-series-forecasting-with-xgboost)
is there an implementation we could use this algorithm for anomaly detection and forecasting together on time series data?

Answer (score 1):

Anomalies by definition are rare. Generally, standard classification algorithms have issues due to the objective function when one of the classes are rare.

If you wanted to detect anomalies, one of the things that you can try is to use xgboost to predict the time series, and then use the residual to determine which are "poorly" predicted by the algorithm and therefore are anomalous.

Comment: How would this work in practice ? Suppose I have a time series with data spanning one year. As I understand it I train a model on a subset of the data (let's say jan-october) and then I predict the values of the remaining months with model and compare the models output to the actual value in my dataset. But then I can only detect anomalies in the last months. How would I go about finding anomalies in the period jan-october ?

Comment: Ideally if your model isn't overfitting during the training period, you can still look at the training residuals. If you're using XGBoost, basically start dialing back the hyper-parameters like # of trees, % of data used, etc. Then plot the training residuals per time point

Comment: I'm actually quite new to modelling so let me make sure I understood correctly. Are you saying that I can keep the same model and apply it the data (jan - october) to predict values and compare to the actual data (jan-october). Concerning overfitting I guess you mean that the model could have "learnt" the existing anomalies in the training data and so in case of overfitting we would not be able to detect the anomalies by using residuals because would predict the anomalous data points. And when you say that I could dial back the hyperparameters this would be to make a simpler model which ...

Comment: which would minimize the risk of overfitting the data. Also is it really a risk of overfitting when anomalies are usually rare events by definition ?

Comment: Yes. And there is always a risk of overfitting your training data. (Some models have higher risks, some have lower risks)